# Trying simple groovy script with grab and RESTClient

Tags: java, groovy

Using Groovy 2.1.7 with JDK 1.7.0_40.

I'm trying to write a very simple prototype groovy script.  It's going to call RESTClient and process the results from a service.

It looks something like this:

```
#! env groovy
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2' )
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.1' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
println("About to create RESTClient.");
service = new RESTClient("http://myhost/")
def diagnostics = service.get(path: "mypath");
println("diagnostics[" + diagnostics + "]");
```

When I run this, I get this:

```
About to create RESTClient.
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
        at monitorStatus.run(monitorStatus.groovy:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
        ... 1 more
```

I saw one mention of needing to put the "@Grab" annotation on a method.  I've tried several variations of this with thosee annotations on a method, but it made no difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I added "-Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true" to my JAVA_OPTS and made some trivial changes to the script.

Here is my current script, with just the url and path modified:

```
#! /usr/bin/env groovy
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2' )
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.2.5' )
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
println("About to create RESTClient.");
service = new RESTClient("http:///")
def diagnostics = service.get(path: "mypath");
println("diagnostics[" + diagnostics + "]");
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
Resolving dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.5 {default=[default]}
Resolving dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.5.2 {default=[default]}
Preparing to download artifact org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.5!httpclient.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.5.2!http-builder.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.4!httpcore.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3!json-lib.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;1.7.11!groovy.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.9!nekohtml.jar
Preparing to download artifact xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2!xml-resolver.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1!commons-collections.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6!ezmorph.jar
Preparing to download artifact antlr#antlr;2.7.7!antlr.jar
Preparing to download artifact asm#asm;3.2!asm.jar
Preparing to download artifact asm#asm-commons;3.2!asm-commons.jar
Preparing to download artifact asm#asm-util;3.2!asm-util.jar
Preparing to download artifact asm#asm-analysis;3.2!asm-analysis.jar
Preparing to download artifact asm#asm-tree;3.2!asm-tree.jar
Preparing to download artifact xerces#xercesImpl;2.8.1!xercesImpl.jar
Preparing to download artifact xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.03!xml-apis.jar
About to create RESTClient.
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
        at monitorSunlightDataSourceStatus.run(monitorSunlightDataSourceStatus.groovy:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
        ... 1 more
```

Does this provide any useful clues?

Comment: I don't believe you need the httpclient grab. Can you try without it?

Comment: You're right, I don't need it.  It gives me the same error without it. :)

Comment: Openjdk? Or the Oracle one?

Comment: Groovy Version: 2.1.7 JVM: 1.7.0_40 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7

Comment: Any reason for http-builder 0.5.2?  You might have better luck with 0.6, the most recent release.

Comment: Because when I tried with either 0.6 or 0.6.0, I got a different error: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.6.0: not found]

Comment: Use 0.6 instead of 0.6.0.

Comment: I tried that.  No difference.  That wasn't the issue, in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to resolve this, but I'm not sure what the problem was.  Someone on the groovy-user list suggested removing ~/.groovy and reinstalling Groovy.  I tried the former by itself first, and that just made the script run slower, but it still failed in the same way.  I then tried both reinstalling Groovy and deleting ~/.groovy, and after that the script was able to execute successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting `~/.m2` directory and also `~/.groovy/grapes directory`.
It worked for me.